# Delphi 10.3.2, Catalina, fails Notarization, but Apple really does notarize

Tags: macos, delphi, deployment

I have followed all the instructions:

1. Create a 'Hello World' program
2. List item Created a Developer Application ID in XCode
3. Copied the new certificate name and entered in the Developer ID Application edit box.
4. I went to Apple Account and created an application password and entered into the provisioning password box.
5. I entered my Apple ID, which is my email address.
6. I built and tried to deploy, but I receive the following error.

[PAClient Error] Error: E5896 2019-10-21 08:46:26.349 altool[17282:641320] *** Error: Apple Services operation failed. Could not find the RequestUUID.

But then, Apple sends me an email:

Dear Robert, Your Mac software has been notarized. You can now export this software and distribute it directly to users.

Bundle Identifier: Project14
Request Identifier: *my identifier *

So, I have an application that was signed during a deployment but then finished with an error. Is there a way that I can finish downloading the notarized program myself and finishing things off?

Embaradero says it works fine in 10.3.3 beta to Mojave, which doesn't help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t have to retrieve a notarized copy of your item.  You may `staple` the notarization to the original by issuing the `stapler` command:

```
xcrun stapler staple /path/to/my/software.app
```

If the item is not stapled, gatekeeper will look for the notarization ticket in its own database online, which requires an internet connection.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Now I need to figure out how to notarize a package using the shell.

Comment: This page gave me the package notarizing details: https://scriptingosx.com/2019/09/notarize-a-command-line-tool/